# How to pass argument in a script for lauterbach

Tags: flash, lauterbach

I have a variable, named option, which can have a value as NOP or TARGET based on the choosebox. I want to pass the value of this argument and create the region:

```
&Option2 = "NOP"
FLASH.Create 1. 0x00FC0000--0x00FC7FFF NOP Quad 0x0002
```

so instead of above line, I would like to pass the argument Option2, but following syntax always give errors:

```
FLASH.Create 1. 0x00FC0000--0x00FC7FFF "&Option2" Quad 0x0002
FLASH.Create 1. 0x00FC0000--0x00FC7FFF Option2 Quad 0x0002
FLASH.Create 1. 0x00FC0000--0x00FC7FFF &Option2 Quad 0x0002
```

what is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any space between the assignment and the value of the argument.

```
&Option="NOP"
FLASH.Create 1. 0x00FC0000--0x00FC7FFF &Option2 Quad 0x0002
```

This would work